# TypeORM query all records from today

Tags: javascript, mysql, typeorm

I am trying to query all records from today but I get nothing, so My question is:
How to query with date validations in TypeORM?

My code:

```
all = await connection
                .createQueryBuilder(Earnings, 't0')
                .addSelect('t3.id', 't3_id')
                .addSelect('t3.UID', 't3_UID')
                .addSelect('t3.name', 't3_name')
                .addSelect('t3.chips', 't3_chips')
                .addSelect('t3.tickets', 't3_tickets')
                .addSelect('t3.masteredLevel', 't3_masteredLevel')
                .addSelect('t2.UID', 't2_UID')
                .addSelect('t2.name', 't2_name')
                .addSelect('t2.rule', 't2_rule')
                .addSelect('t1.id', 't1_id')
                .innerJoin(Questions, 't1', 't0.questionID = t1.id')
                .innerJoin(Lessons, 't2', 't1.lessonUID = t2.UID')
                .innerJoin(Topics, 't3', 't2.topicUID = t3.UID')
                .where('t0.challenge = 1')
                .andWhere('t0.createdAt = :today')
                .andWhere('t0.userID = :userID')
                .setParameters({ userID: user.id })
                .setParameters({ today: moment() })
                .getRawMany()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.andWhere('t0.createdAt = :today')` only selects rows created at the instant of  **today** parameter. You have set this parameter as `moment()`, which is not a date.

Since we can safely assume no rows will be created in the future, your simplest solution here is: `.andWhere('t0.createdAt >= :today')`, which selects rows created AFTER 00:00 today.

You can combine the addWhere and setParameters into one:

`.andWhere('t0.createdAt >= :today', { today: moment().toDate() })  // note moment.toDate()`

Alternatively use the MySql CURDATE() function to get the current date:

`.andWhere('t0.createdAt >= CURDATE()')`

When you test this, I recommend that you turn on TypeOrm full logging so you can see the actual generated SQL and you will be able to quickly solve any problems. See [TypeOrm logging](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md).

Comment: thanks man, ".andWhere('t0.createdAt >= CURDATE()')" what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

**For TypeORM + PSQL**

Sort items by today's date

```
.andWhere('t0.createdAt >= CURRENT_DATE')
```